# how to give back all the items, when filtering not true

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

```js
const minShoeType=["Air Force 1 ", "Air Force 2", Air Force 3]
    
this.example$ = this.route.data.pipe(
        findDictByType('exampeType'),
        switchMap(dictionaries =>
          this.householdStateService.getBaseDataForm().pipe(
            filter(exampleData => exampleData.shoes.brand === 'NIKE'),
            map(exampleData => dictionaries.filter(dictionary => this.minShoeTyes.includes(dictionary.code))),
            defaultIfEmpty(dictionaries)
          )
        )
      );
```

So I have this code, where I get type from dictionary, and filtering for brand and again filtering inside map. And my question is how I can give back all the shoes, not the three from array?

Now if I select other options, it gives back null, because of `defaultifempty`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, you want your second filter to filter on your base array and not the one returned by the first filter ?

Comment: No, i filter my array because if i click nike on the page, only three element displaying from the base array, but if  I don't select nike, I select adidas, I want to display all the adidas shoes from base array